# Is there a variable to identify each batch data in spark streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

In spark streaming, the data is processed according to batch interval. if I set a batch interval of 5 seconds(`val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(5))`):

```
1s~5s is first batch of data
6s~10s is second batch of data
10s~15s is third batch of data
……
```

Is there a variable to identify each batch data in spark streaming? if there is a variable like this:

`var batchID = 0`

I can get value of `batchID` to recognize which batch of the data, or I can filter data by batchID like: `window(……).filter(_.batchId == 1)`.

Or is there any way to distinguish each batch of data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `foreachRDD` which has type `(rdd: RDD[T], time: Time) => Unit`. The time is the marker of the `RDD` in the data Stream, meaning that on two successive calls on two successive batches, the time argument will differ by one batch interval duration.

You can find the API for `foreachRDD` here:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream

If you need to select some `RDD`s for specific time intervals, you can simply use the `slice` function, which is also specified in the link above.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have another question:  `foreachRDD` return `Unit` not `DStream`, I can't print the result to console. Is there any way to debug easily when use `foreachRDD` function?

Comment: You can call `println` from within `foreachRDD`

Comment: when I use `println` like: `.foreachRDD(println(_))`, the result is `MapPartitionsRDD[1] at map at SparkStreaming.scala:19`, what should I do?

Comment: Have you *started* your Spark Streaming context ? (look up the methods start, stop, awaitTermination, in the StreamingContext's API)

Comment: I use `.foreachRDD(_.collect.foreach(println))` and work well. Thank you!

Comment: I find a problem, `time` in `foreachRDD` can mark the `RDD`, but `time` is timestamp, it will change all the time, that is to say, I can't use `time` to filter `RDD`, because I don't know timestamp of each RDD.